# Custom Text Box Component / Element (Not a Control)

Tags: c#, winforms, text, components, gdi+

I am in need of a class that mimics a TextBox control but is not a Control, but instead a custom drawn component or element.

Creating one feels like re-inventing the wheel since I see them everywhere.  For example, in any modern web browser the text boxes are not controls.  Most Winforms controls, especially ToolStrip controls such as ToolStripTextBox, have elements which behave like text boxes (but are not Controls).

I assume that Microsoft doesn't reinvent the wheel for each control they make it.  But most likely their code is proprietary and not public.

Does any one know of an open source solution for this?  I am experienced with GDI+ drawing but a text field is not a trivial task when you consider caret positioning, selection, and inserting text.

Any pointers on how to go about writing the code myself would be appreciated, such as how to calculate the character at a given point.  Should I create a lookup table for the measured width of each possible character?  Or loop through MeasureString to take into account formatting space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find the code you need inside this article/project.  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/161871/Fast-Colored-TextBox-for-syntax-highlighting

Answer (score 0):

Why must it not be a Control?  If you're using Windows Forms, it is far more likely that you really want a control.

Common cases where this type of question might come up are Grid editing.  Instead of a non-control TextBox, what normally happens is that the grid displays simple text in the grid until the user focuses on that grid.  At that point a temporary, real TextBox is inserted for editing.  Leaving that cell throws the TextBox away and the possibly-changed text is now displayed by the Grid.

I assume your situation is similar.  If not, please explain your goals.

Comment: My goal is to create a text field in a custom drawn document canvas.  I have different types of documents which are drawn using GDI+ and support scrolling, zooming, and layers.  I want the flexibility to use antialiased fonts and I want more control over the look in terms of having a transparent background or using gradient brushes instead of solid colors.  How exactly do I scale a TextBox control using a floating point scale factor?

Comment: Is it possible to use WPF instead?  You can include it as a small piece of the overall application rather than replacing what you have.

Comment: No, unfortunately I must integrate this with a Winforms project.

Comment: WPF can be integrated with WinForms, look at the ElementHost control (opposite of WindowsFormsHost which WPF uses to host WinForms controls).  Does that make it possible?

Comment: Probably, but I'm using Winforms with .NET 2.0.  I think ElementHost requires .NET 3.0.  I don't have the option of changing the target framework, it's kept at 2.0 for "compatibility".